# Literal object and function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, object-literal, function-prototypes

I took this test on http://jsperf.com/literal-obj-vs-function-obj and **Literal** wins on FF6, Opera 10, IE8, but the **Function** method faster on Chrome 13.0.782.112, so which one is a better method to use?

```
var A = {
    aa : function(){
        var i, j=[];
        var arr = ['Literal', 'Function'];
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            j[i] = arr[i];
        }
       return j[0];
    }
};
var A1 = A;
var A2 = A1;
A1.foo = ' Test';
alert(A1.aa() + A2.foo);

//Function test
function B(){
    this.bb = function(){
        var i, j=[];
        var arr = ['Literal', 'Function'];
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            j[i] = arr[i];
        }
        return j[1];
    }
}
var B1 = new B();
var B2 = new B();
B.prototype.foo = ' Test';
alert(B1.bb() + B2.foo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell you the truth, the best that I have found is a mix:

```
function C() {
    var i, j = [],
        foo;

    return {
        bb: function() {

            var arr = ['Literal', 'Function'];
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                j[i] = arr[i];
            }
            return j[1];
        },
        setFoo: function(val) {
            foo = val;
        },
        getFoo: function() {
            return foo;
        }
    }
}
var C1 = C();
var C2 = C();
C2.setFoo(' Test');
console.log(C1.bb(), C2.getFoo());
```

Comment: I checked and tested your revision on jsperf and surely is a nice method but I think literal is a good option, just like in Crockford's Bonus Suggestions http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 1):

Whichever one you prefer. Speed should never be a concern unless it becomes a real problem in your app. What you're doing looks like premature optimization to me, which is a waste of time. Wait until you need to optimize your code, then optimize the parts that need to be reworked. This is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses an optimisation called `hidden classes` that allows it to do faster access to object members.

I would bet that this optimisation is enabled only when the object is constructed via `new`, and as a result an object constructed via `new` would have faster member access than an object not constructed via `new`.

Answer (score 0):

well, chrome has around 17% of the market share according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_table). So use literals.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're going to do anything intensive enough for the difference to matter.

Function style constructors give you the option of private variables, which is nice.